# mysql how to replace a column content

Tags: mysql, replace

I using Mysql.

```
Table: Content_T1

id :  int

title : varchar255

content: text
```

my all page content will be save in content columns.

mysql `content` column...  there is some `<img src="http://abc.com/data/img/......">`

But I had change my domain,

so I need change all `<img>` tag

if url =  `http://www.abc.com/data/img/....`

I need change to =  `http://www.def.com/data/img/....`

Just replace this url and path, without affecting other content.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to update `id` 27

Run this first

```
SELECT REPLACE(content,'http://www.abc.com/data/img','http://www.def.com/data/img') newurl
FROM Content_T1 WHERE id = 27;
```

If the result is correct, you can run

```
UPDATE Content_T1
SET content = REPLACE(content,'http://www.abc.com/data/img','http://www.def.com/data/img')
WHERE id = 27;
SELECT content FROM Content_T1 WHERE id = 27;
```

If the result is correct and you are ready to fix all of them, run this query without the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE Content_T1
SET content = REPLACE(content,'http://www.abc.com/data/img','http://www.def.com/data/img');
```

Please, go to a test server and run this. When the results are correct ...

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!